# Requesting PHP6 cleanup

Tags: discussion, feature-request, clean-up

There is a couple of questions about PHP6 at StackOverflow:

- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php6
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php6

Since no one currently knows if and when PHP6 will surface, most of these questions are either pointless, tagged incorrectly or potentially spread false information. Thus, I request cleanup.

Comment: Most of those questions seem fairly legitimate (if a bit "meta"). What's wrong with that?

Comment: @cdeszaq We do not have reliable information about PHP6. It's pointless to ask "Should I learn PHP5 or PHP6" when PHP6 doesn't exist. Just like it's pointless to ask what will be deprecated in it. Even if we should get PHP6 in the future anything said about it now is just speculation because there is no longer a fixed roadmap for it.

Comment: So it's the change from "this stuff is planed" to "we don't really know what's gonna happen anymore" within the PHP development "team" that caused the issue? If that's the case, then I agree that some cleanup would be useful, but a number of the questions I saw when I took a peek are also useful for anyone working on language design or interested in learning about language features, since none of the php features are _new_ and exist in other languages.

Comment: @cdeszaq yeah, but those you mentioned could likely be retagged so they dont mention php6. The php6 branch has been deleted from the SVN. There is a wiki document but afaik this is still all subject to debate so there is nothing definite people could answer right now. But since we want questions that can be answered with facts …

Comment: You've convinced me, as long as "cleanup" doesn't mean "Whole-sale hack-and-slash closure". +1

Comment: @cdeszaq A selective and considerate approach is fine with me, though I admit I'm not keen of giving them the benefit of doubt. If they cant be retagged, bury them.

Comment: I would agree with that sentiment. No point in keeping cruft around, but care must be taken to preserve the diamonds (ok, at least garnets) in the rough.

Comment: Haha, oh, PHP...