# Why is there still a PHP6 tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

In regards to [Requesting PHP6 cleanup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125875/requesting-php6-cleanup), I noticed that a [php6](/questions/tagged/php6) tag still exists in the system.

Even though no questions exist anymore in the system with the [php6](/questions/tagged/php6) tag, when using the synonym link, it says it already exists.

Would it not be beneficial to create a synonym for [php6](/questions/tagged/php6) -> [php](/questions/tagged/php)?

**Note**: [php5](/questions/tagged/php5) is listed as a synonym for [php](/questions/tagged/php).

Answer (score 3):

Since there are no questions tagged [php6](/questions/tagged/php6), it will automagically be removed from the system eventually.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused with the message you got. The tag doesn't currently exist, and **that** is the problem. Read the error message more carefully:

[image: Failed to propose synonym: The suggested edit **must exist** in the system before suggesting it as a synonym!]

I'm not sure if there is a real benefit to having a PHP6 tag synonym since PHP6 doesn't actually exist yet, which is why the tag was killed off in the first place. Chances are if a person is coming here to ask a question about PHP6, it probably doesn't belong here.